# Converting fsoco .json format file into yolov8 format

Tags: json, computer-vision, yolov8

I would like to train yolov8 with fsoco dataset, where the dataset is annotated into below json format.

```
{
    "description": "",
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": 118615272,
            "tagId": 30143178,
            "name": "train",
            "value": null,
            "labelerLogin": "fsocov2",
            "createdAt": "2020-08-11T08:43:40.624Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-11T08:43:40.624Z"
        }
    ],
    "size": {
        "height": 920,
        "width": 2872
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": 889978312,
            "classId": 9993511,
            "description": "",
            "geometryType": "rectangle",
            "labelerLogin": "fsocov2",
            "createdAt": "2020-08-11T08:17:13.366Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-11T08:17:13.366Z",
            "tags": [],
            "classTitle": "blue_cone",
            "points": {
                "exterior": [
                    [
                        2377,
                        198
                    ],
                    [
                        2398,
                        224
                    ]
                ],
                "interior": []
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 889978311,
            "classId": 9993511,
            "description": "",
            "geometryType": "rectangle",
            "labelerLogin": "fsocov2",
            "createdAt": "2020-08-11T08:17:13.366Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-11T08:17:13.366Z",
            "tags": [],
            "classTitle": "blue_cone",
            "points": {
                "exterior": [
                    [
                        2419,
                        189
                    ],
                    [
                        2436,
                        210
                    ]
                ],
                "interior": []
            }
        }
}
```

Now I want to convert into yolov8 acceptance format in python which is

```
<class_id> <x_center> <y_center> <width> <height>
```

can somebody help me out with this?

Also I have checked https://github.com/ultralytics/JSON2YOLO but I didn't find any suitable option for this.